# LINQ pull records from a database where string list is from a model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I have a database of strings that contain IDs.  I need to pass that list into a LINQ query so I can pull the correct records.

```
model.SelectedDealers = db.dealers.Any(a => a.sdealer_name.Contains(UserToEdit.UserViewAccesses.Select(s => s.ViewReferenceNumber)));
```

`SelectedDealers` is of type `dealers`

`ViewReferenceNumber` should be a list of `strings which should match sdealer_name`

So essentially I am trying to find all of the `dealers` whos `sdealer_name` matches the list of `sdealer_names` I have in my `UserToEdit.UserViewAccesses`

I've tried moving parts around and switching them in different spots and can't seem to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any() is just a boolean indicating if there are any results. It doesn't actually return the results.

If I understand what you are after correctly, then this might work:

```
var dealerNames = UserToEdit.UserViewAccesses.Select(s => s.ViewReferenceNumber).ToList();
model.SelectedDealers = db.dealers.Where(a => dealerNames.Contains(a.sdealer_name));
```

Comment: This is giving me the error `Only primitive types of enumeration types are supported in this context.  Unable to create a constant value of type 'dap.models.UserViewAccess'`

Comment: And yes I think that you understand what I am trying to do.  I was just being a space case on .Any...

Comment: I've edited my answer. Try that. I know that using Contains() in a Linq query only works in very limited uses. But I'm pretty sure I've used it like that before.

Comment: No error that time, but it returned no results.  I'll keep playing with it.  2 results exist in dealerNames I'm pretty sure this is what i need tho.

Comment: It's a start. Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

> So essentially I am trying to find all of the dealers whos
>   sdealer_name matches the list of sdealer_names I have in my
>   UserToEdit.UserViewAccesses

```
   var dealersthatmatched = (from d in UserToEdit.UserViewAccesses.sdealer_names
                             where d == sdealer_name
                             select d).ToList()
```

Wish I could have made a comment instead, but as I don't have enough rep I can't. I wish I understood the requirement better, but you seem ready and able to try stuff so perhaps you find this useful.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to supply an answer.  It is missing some key things for it to work, namely, it has to go into db.dealers and find all of those dealers who dealer_names are in my UserToEdit list.  I'll definitely give an upvote if you can make a working LINQ query version.  And don't worry about not being able to comment that all comes in time. :)  If I need to add something to the OP to make it clearer just let me know.

Comment: Hmm, try this or a modification of this that suits your lists.

List<dealer> dealerlist = new List<dealer>();
dealerlist = db.dealers.Where(i=>i.sdealer_name == UserToEdit.Any()).ToList();

Im om my phone, so writing code is a bit treacherous.

Comment: I think this would make it work, tho I haven't tested it just guessing from the above answer that works.  I tend to write more lambda than LINQ.
`var dealerNames = UserToEdit.UserViewAccesses.Select(s => s.ViewReferenceNumber).ToList();
model.SelectedDealers = (from d in db.dealers where dealerNames.contains(d.sdealer_name) select d);`